# Первый элемент массива принимает значение последнего элемента массива

Tags: android, массивы, list, arraylist

Есть класс `itemList`

```
public class itemList implements Serializable
{
    public String nameList;
    public String Tag;
    public ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions;

    public itemList(String nameList, String Tag,ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions)
    {
        this.nameList = nameList;
        this.Tag = Tag;
        this.itemQuestions = itemQuestions;
    }
}
```

В нем есть массив с классом `itemQuestion`

```
public class itemQuestion implements Serializable
{
    public String question;
    public ArrayList<itemAnswer> answer;
    public int quantityTrue;
    public int quantityFalse;

    public itemQuestion(String question,ArrayList<itemAnswer> answer, int quantityTrue, int quantityFalse)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.quantityTrue = quantityTrue;
        this.quantityFalse = quantityFalse;
    }
}
```

А в классе `itemQuestion` есть еще один массив с классом `itemAnswer`

```
public class itemAnswer implements Serializable
{
    public String Answer;
    public boolean trueAnswer;

    public itemAnswer (String Answer, boolean trueAnswer)
    {
        this.Answer = Answer;
        this.trueAnswer = trueAnswer;
    }
}
```

Так вот, в основном активити есть переменная с классом `itemList`

```
public itemList itemListS = new itemList("","arif",new ArrayList<itemQuestion>());
```

Я добавляю к элементу `itemListS` к его массиву `itemQuestions` новый элемент

```
public ArrayList<itemAnswer> answer = new ArrayList<itemAnswer>();

//... Здесь заполняю массив answer и т.д. ... //

itemListS.itemQuestions.add(new itemQuestion(ArifEditText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(), answer, 0, 0));

answer.clear();
```

И вся проблема в том, что когда, к примеру, добавляю новый элемент к массиву `itemQuestions`, то элементы которые уже имеются в массиве принимают значение answer того элемента, который был добавлен последний.

(Дальше пойдут схематичные примеры, поэтому не надо писать, что я не так заполняю массив итд)

К примеру: Допустим что это массив до заполнения

```
// ... Первый элемент ... //
question = "150"
ArrayList<itemAnswer> answer = {1 false,
                               0 false,
                               6 false,
                               5 false};
quantityTrue = 0;
quantityFalse = 0;
```

И тут я добавляю второй элемент

```
// ... Первый элемент ... //
question = "150"
ArrayList<itemAnswer> answer = {2 false,
                               5 false,
                               8 false,
                               7 false};
quantityTrue = 0;
quantityFalse = 0;

// ... Второй элемент ... //
question = "200"
ArrayList<itemAnswer> answer = {2 false,
                               5 false,
                               8 false,
                               7 false};
quantityTrue = 0;
quantityFalse = 0;
```

И как видно, что массив `answer` первого элемента принимает значение `answer` второго элемента, думаю объяснил доступно.

Comment: попробуйте во всех сигнатурах прописать `final`

Comment: по-моему, вы зря описали "схематично". Вы ведь не пересоздаете каждый раз `answer`, а делаете `answer.clear()` и заполняете его новыми элементами?

Comment: @zRrr Это да, то что я описал "схематично" это я описал структуру которая в то время находиться в itemListS.ItemQuestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то странно это все, но спусте день заморочек это все решилось как то так

```
final ArrayList<itemAnswer> answers = new ArrayList<itemAnswer>();

        for (int i=0; i<answer.size(); i++)
        {
            answers.add(new itemAnswer(answer.get(i).Answer, answer.get(i).trueAnswer));
        }

        final itemQuestion itemQuestionAdd = new itemQuestion(ArifEditText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(), answers, 0,0);

        itemListS.itemQuestions.add(itemQuestionAdd);
        itemListS.nameList = nameList.getText().toString();
```

Даже если просто подставлю `final answers = answer` то не работает